# Angular Controller not Instantiated/Working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Maybe its just a very simple answer, but even with the available questions regarding this topic, I cant figure out why my controller is not instantiated.

I have written two `console.log` statements: one in the *app.config.js* and one in the *expenses-stub.component.js* file where the controller is declared. For some reason the first console log is executed, so I know that the app.config is entered. But somehow, my controller is not instantiated.

I hope for some good suggestions to fix this issue :-) Thanks for the help!

My code is as follows:

**HTML snippet**

```
<div>

<div ng-app="expensesApp" class="jumbotron view-container">
    <ng-view class="view-frame"></ng-view>
</div>

</div>

<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>

<link href="expensableApp/app.animation.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="expensableApp/app.js"></script>
<script src="expensableApp/app.config.js"></script>
<script src="expensableApp/expenses-stub/expenses-stub.module.js"></script>
<script src="expensableApp/expenses-stub/expenses-stub.component.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
(function () {

var expensesApp = angular.module('expensesApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute', 'expensesStub']);

})();
```

**app.config.js**

```
angular.module('expensesApp')
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider){
        console.log("Expenses config entered"); //appears in console log
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        $routeProvider
            .when('/expenses', {
                template: '<expenses-page></expenses-page>'
            })
            .otherwise('/expenses')
    }
]);
```

**expenses-stub.module.js**

```
angular.module('expensesStub', []);
```

**expenses-stub.component.js**

```
angular.module('expensesStub')
.component('expensesStub',{
    templateUrl: 'expensableApp/expenses-stub/expenses-page.template.html',
    controller: ['', function ExpensesStubController () {
        //the console log statement below does not appear in the console log, still wondering why...
        console.log("Expenses Controller instantiated!");
    }]
});
```

**expenses-page.template.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="col-xs-12">Hello World!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you're not using it? add `<expenses-stub></expenses-stub>` to your HTML

Comment: Ok, adding `<expenses-stub></expenses-stub>` works, but that means that  `<ng-view class="view-frame"></ng-view>` is not working. Do you might have an explanation/solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

George suggested one solution, in his comment, but this was not working for me since this would me force to remove the `<ng-view>` directive from my HTML. However he put me in the right direction.

I figured out that in the above code I mentioned a wrong template in the `app.config.js`  file. I used the name of the html file as a name for the template, but this had to be the name of the module. I fixed the above app.config file as follows:

```
angular.module('expensesApp')
.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider){
        console.log("Expenses config entered"); //appears in console log
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        $routeProvider
            .when('/expenses', {
                template: '<expenses-stub></expenses-stub>'
            })
            .otherwise('/expenses')
    }
]);
```

This way I am still able to let `<ng-view>` control my view.